# How to earn domination defends in Call of Duty 2019

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare

[image]
The clan I am in is trying to earn points for this week and I was trying to work out the best value.

Without knowing the exact rules of what gives you a defend point, this is hard. I suspect it may be quicker to go for defends rather than rushing the flags.

Does anyone know what the rules are?

Answer (score 2):

found this video which shows the different ways.

1. be close to flag and kill enemy
2. shoot enemy close to flag
3. clear a flag